# Iterate through a list for status till all batch processed

Tags: scala

I am looping all the batch Ids and polling for status other than "pending"  in a loop.

So if a batch status is success /failed, it exists out and removes element from ListBuffer so that it wont process it again.

1. how i can make it more elegant
2. The list may contain None . so how to process only the element which has values.

Data type :  Option[ (String,String,Long)]  //Batch ID , Status and Unique ID
Example :
List (Some("batch1","Pending",123)  , None , Some("batch2","success",124). )

```
val lstBuffer=StatusList.to[ListBuffer]   

var lstBuffer1 = lstBuffer.map(k => (k.get._1, pollStatus(k.get._1) ,k._3)) 

    do {
      for ( i<- lstBuffer1){
        if (i._2 != "success"){
          lst1 -= i
          println(s"${i._1} succeeded for ${i._3}")
        }
        if (i._2 != "failed"){
         lst1 -= i
          println(s"${i._1} failed for ${i._3}")
        }
        
      }
      lst1 = lstBuffer1.map(k => (k._1, pollStatus(k._1) ,k._3))

    }while(lst1.isEmpty)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make it a `Future`:

```
    def awaitCompletion(
       batchId: String, 
       id: String
    ): Future[Boolean] = Future(pollStatus(batchId)).flatMap { 
       case "success" => 
          print(s"$batchId succeeded for $id")
          Future.successful(True)
       case "failed" => 
          print(s"$batchId failed for $id")
          Future.successful(False)
       case _ => awaitCompletion(batchId, id)
    }
```

Now, assuming `batches` is a list of tuples `(batchid, id)` (I dunno why you need a `Option` there, but if you do have it for some reason, just replace `batches` with `batches.flatten` below), you can do something like:

```
    Await.ready(
       Future.traverse(batches)(awaitCompletion.tupled), 1.hour
    )
```

There are a few things that can be improved here (for instance, polling constantly like this is probably not a very good idea, you should have some sort of backoff policy ... perhaps, use a timer with a delay instead of invoking `pollStatus` directly), but this should give you the basic idea, and get you started.

**Update** in response to the question in comments, here is a simple implementation of a delayed execution without blocking based on java `Timer` (if you are using a scala framework like akka or play or something, you are better of using their "native" implementation, but in a "vanilla" scala program, this will do):

```
object Delayed {
  import java.util.{Timer, TimerTask}
  private val timer = new Timer
  def apply[T](delay: Duration)(task: => T): Future[T] = {
    val promise = Promise[T]()
    val tt = new TimerTask {
      override def run(): Unit = promise.success(task)
    }
    timer.schedule(tt, delay.toMillis)
    promise.future
  }
}
```

With this, you can simply replace `Future(pollStatus(batchId))` in `awaitCompletion` above with `Delayed(100.millis)(pollStatus(batchId))` to add a 100 milliseconds delay before each poll.

Comment: if i need to add delay before each poll. where that would go ?

Comment: @byomjan I added an update with a simple delay mechanism based on java `Timer`. Most scala frameworks have their own implementations, if you are using them, you are better of sticking to those, but semantics is usually similar to what I showed. You may also be able to get away with just Future { Thread.sleep(100); pollStatus(batchId, id) } but blocking pooled threads is not very nice. At the very least you have to make sure you have enough of them if you decide to do that.

Comment: how about case _ => { delay(5000) ; awaitCompletion(batchId, id)} . Why complicate :)

Comment: @byomjan  If by `delay(5000)` you mean the timer thing I mentioned then yeah, it'll work (would have to be something like `Delay(5 seconds)(identity).flatMap(awaitCompletion)`, but putting it in the beginning seems slightly more fitting: it just naturally replaces the `Future.apply` call there.  If you mean `Thread.sleep`, that goes back my comment about blocking pooled threads: it's not nice. Thread is a resource, and making it just spin its wheels is never the best solution (even aside from the obvious deadlock and thread starvation concerns if your pool is limited).

Comment: i did not understand this part `Await.ready(
       Future.traverse(batches)(awaitCompletion.tupled)
    )`

Comment: @byomjan That's the actual loop :) It starts `awaitCompletion` for each of the batches, and then waits for all of them to finish

Comment: thanks for clarifying . I am using these features first time :) . `Await.ready(
      Future.traverse(flattenTupleList)(awaitCompletion.tupled)
    )`  I am getting Unspecified Value parameter :atMost:Duration. Kindly help me with that

Comment: @byomjan Sorry about that. Fixed now

Comment: you are much advanced level. :)  As i added Delayed(5 mins) in awaitCompletion in place of Future.  I am not sure what is the 1.hour for ?

Comment: It just limits how long to wait until all batches are completed.

Comment: will this `Future.successful(False)` throw error in case of status failed?

Comment: No, it'll just return false ... like with your original implementation, no errors are thrown here

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand what your code does and how each function should be used.

But making some assumptions like `pollStatus` returns an **Option** of the new status you can do something like this:

```scala
type Data = Option[(String, String, Long)]

def process(data: List[Data]): List[Data] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[Data], acc: List[Data]): List[Data] =
    remaining match {
      case Some((batchId, "success", uniqueId)) :: tail =>
        println(s"${batchId} succeeded for ${uniqueId}")
        loop(remaining = tail, acc)
      
      case Some((batchId, "failed", uniqueId)) :: tail =>
        println(s"${batchId} failed for ${uniqueId}")
        loop(remaining = tail, acc)
      
      case Some((batchId, _, uniqueId)) :: tail =>
        val newStatus = pollStatus(batchId)
        val newElement = newStatus.map(status => (batchId, status, uniqueId))
        loop(remaining = tail, newElement :: acc)
      
      case None :: tail =>
        loop(remaining = tail, acc)
      
      case Nil =>
        acc // Use acc.reverse is preserving order is important.
    }
  
  loop(remaining = data, acc = List.empty)
}

def processUntilAllSuccceded(data: List[Data]): Unit = {
  Iterator.iterate(data)(process).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).foreach(_ => ())
}
```

If actually, you can not have newer `Nones` during a single processing, I would remove all of them from the beginning doing something like `data.collect { case Some(data) => data }` or `data.flatten` *(according to your style preference)* and adapt the code to do not care about **Option**.

---

However, it may be better to also take advantage of **Scala** features like **case classes** and **ADTs** to provide more type safety to the code.

```scala
// Could use Enumeratum or the new enum keyword in Scala 3.
sealed trait Status extends Product with Serializable
object Status {
  final case object Success extends Status
  final case object Failed extends Status
  final case object Pending extends Status
}

// It may be good to use refined types instead of String or Long.
final case class Data(batchId: String, status: Status, uniqueId: Long)

def process(data: List[Option[Data]]): List[Option[Data]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[Option[Data]], acc: List[Option[Data]]): List[Option[Data]] =
    remaining match {
      case Some(Data(batchId, Status.Success, uniqueId)) :: tail =>
        println(s"${batchId} succeeded for ${uniqueId}")
        loop(remaining = tail, acc)
      
      case Some(Data(batchId, Status.Failed, uniqueId)) :: tail =>
        println(s"${batchId} failed for ${uniqueId}")
        loop(remaining = tail, acc)
      
      case Some(Data(batchId, Status.Pending, uniqueId)) :: tail =>
        val newStatus = pollStatus(batchId)
        val newElement = newStatus.map(status => Data(batchId, status, uniqueId))
        loop(remaining = tail, newElement :: acc)
      
      case None :: tail =>
        loop(remaining = tail, acc)
      
      case Nil =>
        acc // Use acc.reverse is preserving order is important.
    }
  
  loop(remaining = data, acc = List.empty)
}

def processUntilAllSuccceded(data: List[Option[Data]]): Unit = {
  Iterator.iterate(data)(process).takeWhile(_.nonEmpty).foreach(_ => ())
}
```

---

*You can see the code running in [**Scastie**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/tpMnAogMSyiSvVGZy0wITQ/8)*.

Comment: `data.collect { case Some(data) => data }` === `data.flatten` :)

Comment: @Dima yeah, I do not like that. - But, still a valid advice, I upvoted the comment and added it to the answer.